# How to manually create an Array of ember-data objects?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have the need to override the find on a specific object in my ember.js app. What I have below works great if I was planning to return a "single" ember-data object, but how would I modify this to return an Array of objects (such that I return a `AdapterPopulatedRecordArray` or `RecordArray` (not sure the difference to be honest)).

```
App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string')
}).reopenClass({                                                                                                                       
    find: function() {
        var result = Ember.Object.create({
          isLoaded: false
        });

        $.getJSON('/api/foos/', function(data) {
          result.setProperties(data);
          result.set('isLoaded', true);
        });

        return result;
    }
});
```

Comment: It only differs for this class? what differs to be precise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can return an array as follows:

```
App.Foo = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string')
}).reopenClass({
    records: [],
    find: function() {
        var self = this;
        $.getJSON('/api/foos/', function(response) {
            response.forEach(function(record){
                self.records.addObject(App.Foo.createRecord(record))                                                           
            }, this)
        });
        return this.records;
    }
});
```

This example (adapted from http://trek.github.com/) returns a simple array. To return a record array (or adapter populated record array) will
require more work but it is the same basic pattern. Have a look at this test for detail on what would be required:

https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/tests/unit/record_array_test.js

Comment: Here you can find more info about receiving data from remote server.
http://trek.github.com/